# Eclipse java debugger consistently 6 lines off of where it should be, in one file

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm having a strange problem when debugging some java code with eclipse (Version: Helios Service Release 2 - Build id: 20110218-0911)

It works fine most of the time, but whenever I step into code in one of the files, the debugger highlights the line which occurs 6 lines behind where I currently 'am' (which I determined from looking at the stack trace). Then when I go deeper into the call tree into yet file, it starts working correctly again. I'm sure that the program I'm debugging and the file eclipse is using are in sync, and I've tried refreshing the project, restarting eclipse, and even removing and re-adding the project, with no luck.

any suggestions?

Comment: Stupid question: are you stepping through a file that is in your Eclipse project, or in a linked project, or from a JAR file?

Comment: @Laf - ahh, I had the jar in the classpath under 'user entries', rather than the project. Changing that fixed it for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: You should accept the answer posted by @ziesemer then ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens quite frequently when working against class-only JAR files where a source attachment has been made - and the attached source doesn't exactly match the class byte-code.  The debugger is working against the line # details included in the classes, but it won't necessarily match the attached source.

Comment: The strange thing is that the jar was built with the source files exactly as they are now, but referencing the project rather than the jar fixed it, so thanks.